# Cloning a task to Multiple Accounts in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a problem that I have been trying to solve and have been hitting Google most of the day with no joy.

I have a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 system and the business is looking to allocate tasks to the sales reps by Account.

So for example we may create a task for "Check product XYZ pricing is correct for Feb promotion"  This task would then be assigned to the Accounts that it applied to, via say an Advanced Find.

I can do this with a workflow but that requires a workflow per task when I will have a number of these tasks, each with a separate list of target Accounts.  I thought maybe use a dialog but those are limited to single account usage.  Set up a Marketing Campaign for a single task looked like too much overhead to be the right way.

So in the ideal world I would select a group of Accounts that meet a specific set of requirements, then create a task (Activity), which would be cloned across the selected Accounts.

Any ideas here?  Or have I missed some basic functionality in the system.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Can you not just create a workflow, then in the accounts view select all the accounts and run the workflow against all of them at once?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am currently doing but you need to create a new workflow for each task. What I am looking for is a generic method to create tasks then assign them to multiple accounts.

Comment: In the CWA you can do as franglais suggested, pick the list of all the accounts, filter the list based on your criteria, then apply the logic to each account. If you need to run the workflow against a subset of accounts, and you are not able to apply the filter if not selecting the accounts manually, your only choice is to spawn multiple workflows, one for each account.

Comment: Applying a workflow to multiple accounts is not the issue. The problem is that each task topic requires

Comment: requires a seperate workflow. For example if I  have 5 task topics to assign to multiple accounts it requires 5 seperate workflows. I was looking for a solution that allows me to complete a task for multiple accounts without multiple workflows. I Will be creating a number of these task topics each month.